# Filling missing age in titanic dataset

Tags: python, pandas

I know there are several hundred solutions on this, but I was wondering if there is a smarter way to fill the panda's data frame missing the age column based on lengthy certain conditions as folows.

```
mean_value = df[(df["Survived"]== 1) & (df["Pclass"] == 1) & (df["Sex"] == "male")
                & (df["Embarked"] == "C") & (df["SibSp"] == 0) & (df["Parch"] == 0)].Age.mean().round(2)

df = df.assign(
    Age=np.where(df.Survived.eq(1) & df.Pclass.eq(1) & df.Sex.eq("male") & df.Embarked.eq("C") &
                 df.SibSp.eq(0) & df.Parch.eq(0) & df.Age.isnull(), mean_value, df.Age)
)
```

Repeating the following for all 6 columns above, with all categorical combinations is too long and bulky, I was wondering if there is a smarter way to do this?

@Ben.T answer:

If I understood your method correctly, this is the "verbose version" of it ?

```
for a in np.unique(df.Survived):
    for b in np.unique(df.Pclass):
        for c in np.unique(df.Sex):
            for d in np.unique(df.SibSp):
                for e in np.unique(df.Parch):
                    for f in np.unique(df.Embarked):
                        mean_value = df[(df["Survived"] == a) & (df["Pclass"] == b) & (df["Sex"] == c)
                                        & (df["SibSp"] == d) & (df["Parch"] == e) & (df["Embarked"] == f)].Age.mean()

                        df = df.assign(Age=np.where(df.Survived.eq(a) & df.Pclass.eq(b) & df.Sex.eq(c) & df.SibSp.eq(d) &
                                                    df.Parch.eq(e) & df.Embarked.eq(f) & df.Age.isnull(), mean_value, df.Age))
```

which is equivalent to this?

```
l_col = ['Survived','Pclass','Sex','Embarked','SibSp','Parch']
df['Age'] = df['Age'].fillna(df.groupby(l_col)['Age'].transform('mean'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#transformation) can do it. It creates for each row the `mean` over the group of all the columns in the `groupby`, and it does it for all the combinations possibles at once. Then using `fillna` with the serie created will fill missing value with the `mean` of the group with same charateristics.

```
l_col = ['Survived','Pclass','Sex','Embarked','SibSp','Parch']
df['Age'] = df['Age'].fillna(df.groupby(l_col)['Age'].transform('mean'))
```

Comment: I added some update on the question to reflect my comment, since the comment area was too short. Not sure why there is different missing amount of values. Maybe I misunderstood this.

Comment: @JosephAdam yes your verbose seems to be the same than the `groupby` method. but for the difference, I can't say for sure as I don't have the data.

Comment: Thanks ! I just figured it out. It was wrong data input from my side. Your methods is super clean.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a variable that combines all of your criteria, and then you can use the ampersand to add more criteria later.

Note, in the seaborn titanic dataset, where I got the data from, the column names are lowercase.

```
criteria = ((df["survived"]== 1) & 
            (df["pclass"] == 1) & 
            (df["sex"] == "male") & 
            (df["embarked"] == "C") & 
            (df["sibsp"] == 0) & 
            (df["parch"] == 0))

fillin = df.loc[criteria, 'age'].mean()

df.loc[criteria & (df['age'].isnull()), 'age'] = fillin
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Eric, but isn't this still super long, since I have to hardcode all criterias ?